# If $\{ a_n \}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\{ a_n - a_{n-1} \}$ is convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{ a_n \}$ is a sequence in real numbers and define $f_n := a_n - a_{n-1}$. Prove that if $\{ f_n \}$ is convergence, then $\{ \frac{a_n}{n} \}$ is convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $n \geq 2$, we have $$\frac{a_{n}}{n} = \frac{\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n} \left( a_{k} -a_{k -1} \right)}{n -1} \frac{n -1}{n} +\frac{a_{1}}{n} \text{.}$$

Now, since $\left( \frac{\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{n} \left( a_{k} -a_{k -1} \right)}{n -1} \right)_{n \geq 2}$ is the Cesàro summation of the sequence $\left( a_{n} -a_{n -1} \right)_{n \geq 2}$, it converges to $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left( a_{n} -a_{n -1} \right)$.

Therefore, the sequence $\left( \frac{a_{n}}{n} \right)_{n \geq 1}$ also converges to $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left( a_{n} -a_{n -1} \right)$.